# Randomly getting elements in a HashMap or HashSet without looping

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

I have roughly 420,000 elements that I need to store easily in a Set or List of some kind. The restrictions though is that I need to be able to pick a random element and that it needs to be fast.

Initially I used an ArrayList and a LinkedList, however with that many elements it was very slow. When I profiled it, I saw that the `equals()` method in the object I was storing was called roughly 21 million times in a very short period of time.

Next I tried a HashSet. What I gain in performance I loose in functionality: I can't pick a random element. HashSet is backed by a HashMap which is backed by an array of `HashMap.Entry` objects. However when I attempted to expose them I was hindered by the crazy private and package-private visibility of the entire Java Collections Framework (even copying and pasting the class didn't work, the JCF is very "Use what we have or roll your own").

What is the best way to randomly select an element stored in a HashSet or HashMap? Due to the size of the collection I would prefer not to use looping.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** I forgot a really important detail: exactly how I use the Collection. I populate the entire Collection at the begging of the table. During the program I pick **and remove** a random element, then pick and remove a few more known elements, then repeat. The constant lookup and changing is what causes the slowness

Comment: when was `equals()` called? What operations do you mostly perform on that collection?

Comment: What is the requirement that you haven't told us about that would require you to call `equals()` on an array list?  Is it uniqueness, where you're calling `contains()` before adding?

Comment: I can't help but notice that 21 million is 50x 420k. I bet you have some loop 100 times that is looping over the entire array until you find the element you randomly chose, averaging 210k each time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pick a random element"? pick an element randomly chosen? Find a specific element? Find the n'th element?

Comment: if you only remove by index, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason why an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList` would need to call `equals()`... although you *don't* want a `LinkedList` here as you want quick random access by index.

An `ArrayList` should be ideal - create it with an appropriate capacity, add all the items to it, and then you can just repeatedly pick a random number in the appropriate range, and call `get(index)` to get the relevant value.

`HashMap` and `HashSet` simply aren't suitable for this.

Comment: I believe it was from the remove operation. I add everything at once at the beginning of the program then throughout constantly do `remove()` and `contains()`. With an ArrayList and LinkedList, both called equals millions of times and were horrendously slow

Comment: @TheLQ: Why didn't you mention that before? You didn't say *anything* about calling `contains()` or `remove()`, neither of which are required for picking a random element. Do you *have* to call `remove()`? If you want all the elements in a random order, but only once each, you could shuffle the list using `Collections.shuffle` - then you don't need to modify it afterwards.

Comment: `remove()` should be able to remove at a specified index; `contains()` will likely need to call `equals()`, though.  For this reason, is there a way you can use the `ArrayList` implementation, but avoid the need to call contains?

Comment: @Jonathan: That would depend on which of the overloaded `remove()` methods he's currently using.

Comment: @Jonathon @Mark I pick all random elements with `remove(int index)`. This does both of the things I want: remove the element and get the element at the index. `contains()` is done multiple times later

Comment: @TheLQ: But why do you need to remove the element at all, and why do you need `contains`? It's very hard to answer the question when it sounds like we've only heard about a third of your requirements...

Comment: @Jon Its part of the algorithm. I'm about to just delete the question and re-ask it since it seems everyone has either mis-read the question or didn't know several requirements, but I'm not sure I can do that now that there's so much activity in it

Comment: @TheLQ: I don't think there's any need to delete the question. But you still haven't answered *why* you need to remove the element. If you just shuffle elements (either ahead of time, or as you go) you can get a sequence of random elements without repeats - was that what you were trying to achieve with the removal? (And no, it wasn't a matter of "misreading" the question - it's a matter of the question as originally written simply not stating all the requirements.)

Answer (score 1):

If *ALL* you need to do is get a large collection of values and pick a random one, then `ArrayList` is (literally) perfect for your needs. You won't get significantly faster (unless you went directly to primitive array, where you lose benefits of abstraction.)

If this is too slow for you, it's because you're using other operations as well. If you update your question with ALL the operations the collection must service, you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call `contains()` (which will call `equals()` many times), you can use `ArrayList.get(randomNumber)` and that will be O(1)

You can't do it with a `HashMap` - it stores the objects internally in an array, where the index = hashcode for the object. Even if you had that table, you'd need to guess which buckets contain objects. So a `HashMap` is not an option for random access.

Comment: I do call `contains()` many times, in addition to that exact line `ArrayList.get(ranodmNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

<s>Assuming that `equals()` calls are because you sort out duplicates with `contains()`, you may want to keep both a `HashSet` (for quick if-already-present lookup) and an `ArrayList` (for quick random access).  Or, if operations don't interleave, build a `HashSet` first, then extract its data with `toArray()` or transform it into `ArrayList` with constructor of the latter.</s>

If your problems are due to `remove()` call on `ArrayList`, don't use it and instead:

1. if you remove not the last element, just replace (with `set()`) the removed element with the last;
2. shrink the list size by 1.

This will of course screw up element order, but apparently you don't need it, judging by description.  Or did you omit another important detail?

Comment: As a side-effect of keeping a parallel `ArrayList` the removal operation at least would go to `O(n)`.

Comment: There was no mention of `remove()` in the beginning.